# VCBuild.exe not found when attempting to install bcrypt, node-gyp and windows-build-tools installed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, build-tools, vcbuild

I'm trying to add bcrypt to my application, and am currently struggling with getting it to build when it is added as a package. I have tried several solutions, but am repeatedly getting this output when attempting to install bcrypt:

```
bcrypt@3.0.7 install C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@10.5.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framew
ork 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it i
s installed elsewhere.  [C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\MAIC\\MAIC-API\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\MAIC\\MAIC-API\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\MAIC\\MAIC-API\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\MAIC\MAIC-API\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN maic-api@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-01T19_21_21_049Z-debug.log
```

As mentioned in the title, I've attempted installing windows-build-tools for npm as well as Build tools for Visual Studio 2019 (which I already had installed). What might I be missing here?

Comment: have you tried below solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things :

- Uninstall any other previous installation for MSBuild tool if any other than below one.
- Uninstall windows-build-tools
- `npm cache clean -f`

Run below command with **Admin** right

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

Then try to install

```
npm install bcrypt
```